# I am trying to build a quiz app in react native, but I am having problem navigating to Previous quotes

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to build a quiz app in react native, but I am having problem navigating to Previous quotes.
This is my code, the prevQuote function isn't working.

```
prevQuote = () => {
    const { activeQuoteIndex } = this.state;
    let prevQuote = activeQuoteIndex;
    this.setState({
        prevQuote: activeQuoteIndex - 1,
    });
};

nextQuote = () => {
    const { activeQuoteIndex } = this.state;

    if (activeQuoteIndex < quotes.length - 1) {
        this.setState({
            activeQuoteIndex: Math.floor(Math.random() * activeQuoteIndex + 10),
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `setState` with a callback like so:

```
this.setState((state) => ({
    prevQuote: state.activeQuoteIndex - 1,
});
```

More info [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

Comment: Is it failing to change `prevQuote`?

Comment: It’s not responsive, I just pressed it and nothing happened.